# Why is IDLE's Shell color coding keywords in user response to input(prompt)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyword, python-idle

I'm working on a Python 3 program that takes input from the user via the Python Shell. For some reason when I enter the information into the shell (once the input asks for info...), it's coloring keywords & functions with specific colors.

For example, if I type in "John is blue". It will color the word "is" as a keyword (Which it technically is but this is string input).

I haven't been able to bring up anything relevant on google so I'm bring the question here. Thanks.

Here is the code that runs the input.

```
    if __name__ == '__main__':

            global string
            string = str(input('Enter info: '))
            string = bytes(string.encode("utf-8"))
            c = cont.key_gen_01()
            c.func_01()



            run_a = obf_01()
            run_a.func_02()
           #run_a.func_03()
            run_a.func_04()

            run_a.func_05(string)
```

Screen shot:

[image: Python input results]

Comment: Are you using a particular IDE? If you're not sure, can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Python's `input()` function doesn't do any coloring. If you see any syntax highlighting being applied, it'll be **something else**, the software that is handling the terminal functions taking the input from the user.

Comment: That isn't "Python shell", it's IDLE, which I would say most Python programmers rarely even use...

Comment: Well that's not true, the actual program header calls itself "Python Shell", additionally I would argue that a lot of python programmers (network programmers) use the shell for scripting, etc..

Comment: Right, you are using IDLE. This isn't a feature of the Python  language, it is a feature of that specific shell implementation. Different IDEs and shell implementations will produce different results. All `input()` does is talk to the `sys.stdin`, `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` objects (handing over to [`readline`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/readline.html) if connected to a TTY).

Comment: @KodyEvangelistDibble, "the shell" is used by effectively all Python developers, sure, if you mean that generically as in the REPL. If you mean IDLE in particular, though? I've yet to see *anyone* use it in a professional setting (except maybe on their first day if coming from a non-Python background), and Python has been involved in some respect through most of my ~20-year career (which included a stint as dev lead at an exclusively-Python-focused shop). And what you have here is *very much* an IDLE-specific problem.

Comment: Thank you all for the depth of checking into this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Colorizing in IDLE editor and Shell windows is done by the IDLE syntax colorizer. In Shell, it also colors console prompts ('>>> '), internal IDLE errors (now extremely rare), user code tracebacks, and user code output.  (Colors can all be customized on the Highlights tab of the Settings dialog.)  So the colorizer should not be turned off between code entries.

Unless your program is requesting entry of python code, I consider colorizing input() responses to be a minor bug.  But it is not obvious how to tell the colorizer to ignore them.  To a display, input() prompts are normal output.  Besides which, responses can be entered before the prompt.  Try the following with or without hitting ENTER before the prompt.

```
import time; time.sleep(5); s = input('what??? '); print(s)
```

The above also works in python, but at least in Windows Console, I don't see the entry until the prompt is displayed.

Answer (score 2):

The Python `input()` function doesn't and can't do anything with how text you enter is displayed. It merely receives text after it has been typed and you hit enter. Instead, the color changes are applied by the IDLE shell window, which implements the input and output environment that the Python interpreter is connected to.

The IDLE Python shell treats *all* user input as Python source code when it comes to highlighting. This is just a change in how the text is rendered on your display, it has no influence on what string value is being returned from the `input()` function.

Other environments (IDE consoles, terminal windows, notebook UIs, etc) that can act as front-end displays for a Python interactive interpreter each can have their own specific ways of treating text.

Answer (score 0):

You can print syntax highlighted text using python pygments
A good way to get started with is the `prompt_toolkit` moudle, comes with support for pygments and ALOT of command line features

Then you can create an `prompt()` which is input, and set the pygments lexer

check the `prompt_toolkit` docs or https://replit.com/@CodinUser/PyShell-15 to see a real life use of the syntax highlighting input pygments prompt_toolkit